# Randomly replace letters in word

Tags: ruby

I tried to write a function which will be able to randomly change letters in word except first and last one.

```
def fun(string)
z=0
s=string.size
tab=string
a=(1...s-1).to_a.sample s-1
    for i in 1...(s-1)
        puts tab[i].replace(string[a[z]])
        z=z+1
    end
    puts tab
end
fun("sample")
```

My output is:

```
p
l
a
m
sample
```

Anybody know how to make it my tab be correct?
it seems to change in for block, because in output was 'plamp' so it's random as I wanted but if I want to print the whole word (splampe) it doesn't working. :(

Comment: can you explain the desired behavior better?

Comment: Are you asking about the problem itself or about tab variable?

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
def fun(string)
  first, *middle, last = string.chars
  [first, middle.shuffle, last].join
end

fun("sample") #=> "smalpe"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'sample'
[s[0], s[1..-2].chars.shuffle, s[-1]].join
# => "slpmae"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
def fun(string)
  first = string[0]
  last = string[-1]
  middle = string[1..-2]
  puts "#{first}#{middle.split('').shuffle.join}#{last}"
end

fun('sample')
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some problems with your function. First, when you say `tab=string`, tab is now a reference to string, so, when you change characters on tab you change the string characters too. I think that for clarity is better to keep the index of sample `(1....n)`to reference the position in the original array.

I suggest the usage of tab as a new array.

```
def fun(string)
  if string.length <= 2
        return 
  z=1
  s=string.size
  tab = []
  tab[0] = string[0]
  a=(1...s-1).to_a.sample(s-1)

  (1...s-1).to_a.each do |i|
     tab[z] = string[a[i - 1]]
     z=z+1
  end

  tab.push string[string.size-1]
  tab.join('')

end

fun("sample")
=> "spalme"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a block:

```
def inner_jumble(str)
  str.sub(/(?<=\w)\w{2,}(?=\w)/) { |s| s.chars.shuffle.join }
end

inner_jumble("pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis") # *
  #=> "poovcanaiimsllinoonroinuicclprsciscuoooomtces"

inner_jumble("what ho, fellow coders?")
  #=> "waht ho, folelw coedrs?"
```

- `(?<=\w)` is a ("zero-width") positive look-behind that requires the match to immediately follow a word character.
- `(?=\w)` is a ("zero-width") positive look-ahead that requires the match to be followed immediately by a word character.
- You could use `\w\w+` in place of `\w{2,}` for matching two or more consecutive word characters.
- If you only want it to apply to individual words, you can use `gsub` or `sub`.

*A lung disease caused by inhaling very fine ash and sand dust, supposedly the longest word in some English dictionaries.